# Help with really confusing venn diagram

Tags: logic

So this is by far the most confusing venn diagram problem i've ever done. Can someone help me out? I know that Real numbers contain rational, and rational contain integers, but i get really confused after that.

Here's the original question:

Draw a single venn diagram showing the subset relations between the sets Z, R, Q, Z+, Z0+, R+,R- and {0}.

Z+ is positive integers excluding 0
Z0+ is positive integers including 0
R+ is positive real numbers
R- is negative real numbers.

Comment: Where does your confusion lie? Clearly $\mathbb{R}^+ \subset \mathbb{R}$ and the same with $\mathbb{R}^{-1}$ and then generalise that with the integers and rationals?

Answer (score 1):

First draw the Venn diagram for $\mathbb{Z}\subset \mathbb{Q}\subset\mathbb{R}$ as three ovals.

Now divide all three ovals in half by a vertical line down the middle. To the right of this line is $\mathbb{Z^{0+}}\subset \mathbb{Q^{0+}}\subset\mathbb{R^{0+}}$, to the left are the negative numbers.

Finally draw a second vertical line, to the right of the previous one; to its right are just the positive numbers, and between the two lines is just 0.

Answer (score 0):

Some helpful questions:
Does Zo+ contain Z+?
Does R+ contain Zo+?  How about Z+?
Which ones is $\{0\}$ included in?

R contains all the rest, so you can start by drawing one large circle for it.  Really it is the universe.  Then place R+,R-,Q,$\{0\}$  Now get the Z's